# Release an ios application?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, release

I've an iOS project developed by someone else, now I have to update it and build a release for client so that they test it.
I've updated it and while archive it in release mode,  get error-

> The identity 'iPhone Developer: XYZ' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain

I am new to iOS. I have some idea that I have to change developer id or something similar in certificate. But do not know how. Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do an "Ad Hoc" distribution.

1. Build your App for "Release".
2. Go to the "Organizer" and select the Archive.
3. Select your build in the Archive.
4. Use the "Distribute" button and select the middle radio button. "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc Distribution".

That will produce a .ipa and ask you where you want to save it. You can put that on your desktop and distribute it.

In order to build an Ad Hoc Build, you have to get yourself an "Ad Hoc Distribution" certificate. You do that in the Apple iPhone Developer site in the provisioning portal area, located here:
[iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action)

You will also need to authorize the devices you want run test versions on in the same way you authorized your own devices for development.

If you have to run the App on many test devices and the testers are not technical. I suggest you take a look at a pretty good service online called "TestFlightApp".

Answer (score 2):

You need to have Apple development certificate and .p12 file of that account of which that provisioning profile exists.

If you don't have, you need to create it from keychain, by requesting a certificate from authorised authority->generate csr and submit in you developer account.

hope it helps you........

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a valid keychain item for the developer certificate, is what the error is telling you. It's a case of creating one and installing it.

But for delivering a test build - you need to create an adhoc distribution, using a distribution certificate that has the test device's udid included.

In either case - and for further troubleshooting - Apple have a handy [Technical Note](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html) for dealing with these kinds of issues and how to solve them.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to your project in `Build Settings -> Code Signing -> Code Signing Identity`, you can change the signing certificate to your own.